# Spring Integration using MqttV5 to print logs on the status of the Mqtt

Tags: java, spring-boot, mqtt

I'm currently using spring integration with mqttv5. I'm using the Mqttv5PahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter class and this adaptor will be use by an IntegrationFlow. I have set the connection options to automatic reconnect to mqtt when disconnected. The function is working well, however I need to print out the logs when the adaptor is attempting to reconnect, as well as "connected to mqtt" and "disconnected to mqtt" messages.

Anyone have any solutions on this?

Thank you in advance!